# Scraping data from a word document Questionnaire into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I need to copy the answer of 50 questions in word into excel.  The word document also contains tables of which i need this information. here is a link to the first part of the questionnaire https://ibb.co/HGkgq6P and here is a link to the how the tables look in the file: https://ibb.co/zPmwPdW

I had an idea of creating bookmarks for each question and then pasting in what was after the bookmark.  i found the below code but while there is no error the code doesnt paste anything.

```
sub TryThis()
Dim oWord As Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.document
Dim vBkMarks As Variant
Dim vRecord
Dim rRecord As Range
Dim nFields As Long
Dim i As Long

vBkMarks = Array("Bookmark1", "Bookmark2", "Bookmark3") 'etc...
ReDim vRecord(LBound(vBkMarks) To UBound(vBkMarks))
nFields = UBound(vBkMarks) - LBound(vBkMarks) + 1
On Error Resume Next
Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If oWord Is Nothing Then _
Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set oDoc = oWord.ActiveDocument
For i = LBound(vBkMarks) To UBound(vBkMarks)
vRecord(i) = oDoc.Bookmarks(vBkMarks(i)).Range.Text
Next i
With Sheets("DataTable")
.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
1, nFields).Value = vRecord
End With
End Sub
```

could you try and help me?

Thanks

Comment: `oDoc.Bookmarks(vBkMarks(i)).Range.Text` will only return anything if the bookmark encloses the text. It cannot return any text that comes after the bookmark's endpoint as that isn't in `Bookmarks(n).Range`

Comment: Timothy thanks for the reply.  I see what you mean however each form is different is the a way to copy the answers to questions in word to excel if the answers are sometimes in tables. Sometimes free text next to the question. Sometimes text in a macro box next to question? Thanks

Comment: There is always a way, but in this instance there won't be just one way. Unless the document has been designed from the start to be processed in this way it is going to be difficult. It will also be very difficult for anyone here to help you without having the document, and is in any case probably beyond the scope of a single question.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I will share an image of the document on Imgur tomorrow if that's ok? Or I can send the document somewhere to you to have a look and see if it is possible at least?

Comment: Unfortunately I won’t have enough time to look at it.

Comment: HI Timothy whenever you have time if you could take a lok at the img links i posted id be most greatful thanks!

Comment: This has now gone way beyond the scope of your original question. Please take time to review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As a pointer for your research the second screenshot appears to show Word form fields. When you ask a new question please ensure that you explain exactly what it is that you are trying to achieve, because that will affect answers given. For example, do you have existing questionnaires that contain data you want to process, or are you trying to design a questionnaire that can then be processed into Excel?